# Webscraping in excel vba, anyway to speed up process?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am working on a web-scraper in VBA excel.

Due to the mechanics of the website I am scraping, I have to conduct it via excel, as the website is a government platform that validates via a file located on an authorised computer from internet explorer, typically i'd have used python or parsehub, but here we are.

The issue I have encountered is that I am scraping approximately 6,600 unique pages (all formatted exactly the same) and it currently takes between 3 to 5 seconds to load each page, which leads to the macro having to run for between 6 to 9 hours.

My question is regarding the mechanics, given i'm restricted in how fast a webpage can load, would it be possible or feasible to run the process for multiple links at a time, rather then opening one at a time, open say, 10 at a time? Or is it far more likely that the bottle neck is my internet connection rather then IE speed?

Just brain storming here.

Comment: Have you searched on here - many posts about vba web scraping...

Comment: If you want to go faster, have a look on how to use `XmlHttpRequest` (hoping your website allows to send requests like that). If you have to stick to robotic scraping, then you can for example create 6 instances (instead of 1) of `InternetExplorer.Application` and give pages `1-999` to the first, `1000-1999` to the second etc. - consider that VBA is a single-threaded process, you won't be able to launch in parallel the 6 `InternetExplorer` using the same macro, so you will have to have 6 Excel instances each one running the same macro on a different range of pages.

Comment: Matteo, thats an interesting idea! So I could batch up multiple excel instances using standard vba like: Sub OpenNewExcelInstance()
 
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlApp = Nothing
 
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium Basic so you can manipulate Google Chrome, and with selenium or IE VBA you can run multiples instances and run Javascript Scripts assync.

I think the best way is too use HTTPRequest if the pages is not dynamic (Who changes with javascript functions)